# Is $\sigma(X,Y)= \sigma(X,XY)$?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $X,Y$ be two independent continuous random variables supported on $\mathbb R^+$. Is it true that $\sigma(X,Y)= \sigma(X,XY)$ ?

I have that $\sigma(X, X Y) \subseteq \sigma(X, Y)$, but not the other inclusion yet.

Comment: $X = 0$ is a counterexample.

Comment: continuous random variables only.

Comment: In that case, @DominikKutek answer is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $\sigma (X,Y)$ is $\sigma-$field generated by vector $(X,Y)$. Take function $f:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ via formula $$f(x,y) = (x,xy)$$, by that $f(X,Y) = (X,XY)$ from which (and fact that $\sigma(f(Z)) \subset \sigma(Z)$ for any random variable $Z$ and borel $f$) we get $\sigma(X,XY) \subset \sigma(X,Y)$

But, starting with vector $(X,XY)$, let $W=XY$ (just for notation) and let $g:\mathbb R_+^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ via formula (we're using $X > 0$) $$g(x,w) = (x,\frac{w}{x})$$

then $g(X,W)=g(X,XY) = (X,Y)$ and hence $\sigma(X,Y) \subset \sigma(X,XY)$ which gives us $$ \sigma(X,Y) = \sigma(X,XY)$$

As you can see, I didn't use assumption about independence, nor distribution of $X,Y$. It all matters that function $(x,y) \to (x,xy)$ is invertible as a function $\mathbb R_+^2 \to \mathbb R_+^2$ (in fact we can only assume that $X>0$)